# Travis CI + NuGet yields Invalid certificate error

Tags: mono, nuget, travis-ci

I'm trying to use NuGet on Travis.

```
- sudo apt-get -qq -y update
- sudo apt-get -qq -y install mono-complete gtk-sharp2
- wget https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe
- mono ./nuget.exe install ILMerge -Version 2.14.1208
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'ILMerge.2.14.1208' with respect to project '/home/travis/build/craftr-build/craftr/build/.nuget-artifacts', targeting 'Any,Version=v0.0'
Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b0109
```

I have tried various recommendations from what I found on Google, for example using the following before trying to use NuGet:

```
- mozroots --import --sync
- yes | certmgr -ssl -m https://go.microsoft.com
- yes | certmgr -ssl -m https://nugetgallery.blob.core.windows.net
- yes | certmgr -ssl -m https://nuget.org
```

Unfortunately the mozroot command gives

```
Downloading from 'http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt?raw=1'...
Couldn't retrieve the file using the supplied information.
```

Leaving out the mozroots command gives the same NuGet error.

How can I get NuGet to work on Travis?

Answer (score 1):

I just used the APT Addon now. I found the sourcelinse and key_urls in another Mono project [here](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/master/.travis.yml)

```
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - sourceline: deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian trusty/snapshots/5.2.0.224 main
        key_url: http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xA6A19B38D3D831EF
      - sourceline: deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-trusty-prod trusty main
        key_url: https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
      - packages:
    packages:
      - mono-devel
      - ca-certificates-mono
```